# Plotting shortened sets with mixed boundaries

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a figure showing how $x \ge y \ge 0$ is divided among e.g. the following sets:

1. $0 < x \le \frac{1}{2}, 0 < y \le x$
2. $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1, 0 < y \le 1 - x$
3. $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1, 1 - x < y \le x$
4. $x = 1, y = 0$
5. $x = 1, 0 < y \le 1$
6. $x = 0, y = 0$
7. $0 < x < 1, y = 0$

The figure, below, shows (in red) a hand-drawn version of what I want.  (The numbers correspond to those listed above.)

Normally I would use `\filldraw` with `tikzpicture` (allowing filling).  Here, there are two twists:

1. the boundaries of any single set can have both `solid` and `dashed` components.  (This is the lesser problem: there seem to be fixes online already, although I've not yet seen an elegant one.)
2. I want to `shorten` the boundaries, allowing us to see which of the abutting sets contains their boundary.  (This is the bigger problem.)

[image: hand-drawn version of desired output in red]

Comment: I have to say I'm a little bit confused. A drawing of the expected output would be nice.

Comment: What does, say, $1,0$ mean as a set in the plane?

Comment: thanks SebGlav: with some embarrassment, I've added a hand-drawn version; Bernard: I've clarified the notation.